# Does the Fourier series of this function converge to $f(t)$ for all $t$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have the function

$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2} + t & \text{when, } -\dfrac{1}{2} < t \le 0,\\
\dfrac{1}{2} - t & \text{when, } 0 < t \le \dfrac{1}{2}.
\end{cases}
$$

and its periodic extension, $f(t + 1) = f(t)$.

I calculated that $\lim_{t \to 1/2^+} f(t) = \lim_{t \to -1/2^+} f(t + 1) = 1 \not = \lim_{t \to 1/2^-} = 0$.

We know that, if $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$ are bounded and piecewise continuous on $[-L, L]$, then the Fourier series converges to $f(t)$ except at points of discontinuity, where it instead converges to $\dfrac{f(t^+) + f(t^-)}{2}$ where $f(t^+)$ is the right-hand limit and $f(t^-)$ is the left-hand limit.

Therefore, would I be correct in saying that the Fourier series of this function DOES NOT converge to $f(t)$ for all $t$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my work.

Comment: Actually, $$\lim_{t\to \frac{1}{2}^+} f(t) = \lim_{t \to -\frac{1}{2}^+} f(t) = 0.$$ The function is Lipschitz continuous, so the Fourier series even converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for the response. So what's wrong with my reasoning $\lim_{t \to 1/2^+} f(t) = \lim_{t \to -1/2^+} f(t + 1) = 1 \not = \lim_{t \to 1/2^-} = 0$?

Comment: I don't know your reasoning, but your mistake is that $$\lim_{t\to -\frac{1}{2}^+} \biggl(\frac{1}{2} + t\biggr) = \frac{1}{2} + \lim_{t\to -\frac{1}{2}^+} t = \frac{1}{2} + \biggl(-\frac{1}{2}\biggr) = 0 \neq 1.$$

Comment: That's probably easier to avoid if one writes $f$ as $f(t) = \frac{1}{2} - \lvert t\rvert$ for $\lvert t\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer The $f(t + 1)$ is supposed to take advantage of the periodicity of the function. Given this, why is $\lim_{t \to 1/2^+} f(t) = \lim_{t \to -1/2^+} f(t + 1) = 1 \not = \lim_{t \to 1/2^-} = 0$ incorrect? It was one of my lecturers who actually said that doing something like $\lim_{t \to 1/2^+} f(t) = \lim_{t \to -1/2^+} f(t + 1) = 1$ is valid, which is why I'm confused here.

Comment: The first part, $$\lim_{t \to \frac{1}{2}^+} f(t) = \lim_{t \to -\frac{1}{2}^+} f(t+1),$$ is valid. You just have the wrong limit. Note that by periodicity $f(t+1) = f(t)$, so the limit you want to compute is (equal to) $$\lim_{t\to -\frac{1}{2}^+} f(t) = 0.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer I've spent much time thinking about this, and I think your last comment is the one thing that finally made it "click". Thank you. :)